# figuring out all the components to a relatively simple looking macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out what the following is actually doing:

```
Sub ZoneTarget()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Dim myTarget As Variant

Sheets("Zones").Select

For i = 3 To 30
    myTarget = Cells(i, 20).Value
    If myTarget = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If
'    Application.CutCopyMode = False
'    Cells(i, 18).GoalSeek Goal:=myTarget, ChangingCell:=Cells(i, 8)
    If Cells(i, 21).Value < -0.05 / 100 Or Cells(i, 21).Value > 0.05 / 100 Then
        Cells(i, 8).Value = Round(Cells(i, 8).Value * (1 + Cells(i, 21).Value), 6)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

I've modified the worksheet, and now the macro is no longer working. Once I've figure out what is being done I can hopefully update the right part to make it work again.

From what I can tell the following is supposed to happen:

On the "Zones" tab
In rows 3 to 30
In column 20 (T)
But only until the row where column T is not blank

Where column 21 (U), in said rows is either less than -0.05 or greater than 0.05
Then value in column 8 (H) should be multiplied by one plus value in column 21 (U)
That value should be rounded

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, but when I run the macro it breaks.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `either less than -0.05 or greater than 0.05` should be `either less than -0.0005 or greater than 0.0005` . there is division by 100 on both of these values. Also do until T is blank

Comment: change `Sheets("Zones").Select` to `Sheets("Zones").Activate` . I would use `With Sheets("Zones")` and change `Cells` to (dot) `.Cells` . Less prone to errors in more complex code. Also `Dim ws As Worksheet` and `Set ws = Worksheets("Zones")` then use `ws.Cells(` is exacting and you can have different variables for different worksheets. Just depends on how complex the code will be.

Comment: What error message does it give you when it 'breaks'?